# primeng table p-table column and data overlapping issue on browser window resizing

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng p-table in my angular application.
On running application my table look like below:
[image]

On resizing the browser window(say decreasing the width of window), table headers and data are overlapped.See the below screen shot:

[image]

You can refer the code from below stackblitz link to reproduce the issue:

[stackblitz code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-45jp2s?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I have tried the below workaround using css:

```
.ui-table-scrollable-header{  min-width: 300px !important;}
 .ui-table-scrollable-body{ min-width: 300px !important;}
 th{  word-break: break-all;}
```

What you think about the above workaround.
Link with above workaround implemented:

[I have tried this, workaround using CSS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-jartgk)

Comment: Please learn to use the correct tags. This question is in no way PrimeFaces related (beside PrimeTek using the domain)

Comment: Will keep in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

primeng table is a component full of feature two of theme can solve this problem ,
column resize so depend on user preference can change the column width to see extra information and the other is responsive so the table can support small size screen like mobile.

template

```html
<p-table [columns]="columnDefinitions" [value]="dataSet" [resizableColumns]="true" [responsive]="true">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pResizableColumn>
                {{col.name}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns" class="ui-resizable-column">
                              <span class="ui-column-title">{{col.name}}</span>

                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

[image: small screen preview]

[Column Resize](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colresize),[responsive](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/responsive)

check the live [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-jyn5a7)

**Update**

we can set the columns to be resizable and set tinital state of the columnd with with these options `[resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="expand"` , the main problem is resize happen at run time so we will set the initial state of the columns size with table state feature like this

```js
localStorage.setItem(
 'statedemo-local',
 '{"columnWidths":"250,200,400,250"}'
);
```

this will set the columns width size and because we set the resize to expand we will see a horizontal scroll bar.

```html
<p-table [columns]="columnDefinitions" [value]="dataSet" [resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="expand" stateStorage="local" stateKey="statedemo-local">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pResizableColumn>
                {{col.name}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns" class="ui-resizable-column">
                              <span class="ui-column-title">{{col.name}}</span>

                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-eag3wx)

Comment: but my requirement is that user will run application only in desktop.I need to fix the UI for desktop(without breaking the UI when user resize the window), table column and header should be visible(horizontal scroll is acceptable) when window is resized

Comment: I want to achieve the result something like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-jartgk

Comment: I have find a trick to do this , I will update my answer base of column resize

Comment: @SureshNegi I have update my answer now the table will expand and you will have a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: @SureshNegi I try to solve this by using primeng table feature as possible

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to happen on resize? You can either set the font-size using vw (viewport width) to make the font grow/shrink on resize, or you can set the overflow property to hide or scroll or whatever you think fits best, example add this to your css-file:

```
th, td{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or you can use word-break if you want to break the word at any character to prevent overflow.

```
td, th{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

For horizontal scrolling add:

```
th, td {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the column width fixed(not changing on browser resizing) and showing the horizontal scroll bar if window width is decreased

Comment: unable to see the changes made by you.

Comment: Add `th, td { overflow-x: auto;}`

Comment: Looks ugly if th,td overflow :auto.How about this workaround which I found:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-jartgk